# Handling on item click in Widget ListView [Android]

Tags: android, listview, widget

I've been searching this for weeks now but I can't find an answer. I'm trying to create a `ListView` inside a `widget`. I managed to populate the `ListView`. My problem is when I click an item inside the `ListView` I wanted to open an `Activity` and passing the `Id` of that item to the `Activity` I called. But it seems I can't get the passed `Id` correctly it is always `null` when going to the `Activity` I called.

Here is my code

WidgetProvier

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
 public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int[] appWidgetIds) {
....
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = updateWidgetListView(context,
                appWidgetIds[i]);


        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds[i], R.id.listViewWidget);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], remoteViews);
    }

    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}

  private RemoteViews updateWidgetListView(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
  //For ListView
  Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
  svcIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
  svcIntent.setData(Uri.parse(svcIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
 remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(appWidgetId, R.id.listViewWidget, svcIntent);
    //When item is clicked on ListView
    Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, ActivityOne.class);
    PendingIntent startActivityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, startActivityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.listViewWidget, startActivityPendingIntent); 

 return remoteViews;
}
```

WidgetService

```
public class WidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {

@Override
public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
    return (new ListProvider(this.getApplicationContext(), intent));
}
}
```

ListProvider

```
 @Override
 public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
 final RemoteViews widgetRow = new RemoteViews(
        context.getPackageName(), R.layout.list_row);

ListItem listItem = listItemList.get(position);
widgetRow.setTextViewText(R.id.txtID, listItem.id);

//Pass the ID to ActivityOne 
Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
fillInIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID", listItem.id);
widgetRow.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.llRow, fillInIntent);

return widgetRow;
}
```

ActivityOne

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {
  String mID;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {

....
 mID = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ID");
....
}
```

I'm populating my `ListView` using a `Web Service` that is inside my `ListProvider` and calling it on `onDataSetChanged`. When debugging it, while the `List` is being populated it also puts all the data in `EXTRA_ID`, maybe it was the reason why when the `Activity` is opened is gets confuse and returns null instead, I'm not sure why how to fix this. Please guide me how to solve this. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You haven't added code from your `ActivityOne` where you are getting `null` instead of an `Id`.

Comment: @Abbas I've added my `ActivityOne`

Comment: Try and add `EXTRA_ID` in `Intent` from `updateWidgetListView()`.

Comment: @Abbas Like this `startActivityIntent.putExtra("EXTRA_ID2", intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ID"); );` ? I'm wondering on how can I get the Id from the `ListProvider`

Comment: Why don't you first add a hard coded value to start with and see if you get that in your `Activity` and not null. Worry about details later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/StackWidget/) I tried following it and changes how the data is set and then on the `onReceive` in my `AppWidgetProvider` I call there my `ActivityOne` and passed the data from what I get in the `Bundle`. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269559/how-to-start-activity-from-android-appwidget) also help me to start an `Activity` inside the `onReceive` inside the `AppWidgetProvider`. I'm just encountering app crashes when removing the widget on home screen. Will update this answer when I found out how to solve it.

***Edit***

I got to solve the crashing part I forgot to add the `onDelete` and then add `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged` as well for the `ListView` its working fine now.